# MapboxGL JS - Shape layer type

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a map with a vector tile source containing thousands of geojson points.
I can display the points on a map, showing a circle for each one of them, using a [circle](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layers-circle) type layer.

I would like to do the same, but using different shapes, such as square and triangle. Isn't there a built-in way to do this ? What are my options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is of any use, this is what I did :

1. I created a set of svg images in different colors, by editing the maki shape icons provided at https://www.mapbox.com/maki-icons/editor/
2. I converted them to a jpg sprite file and a json descriptor using https://github.com/mapbox/spritezero-cli
3. I created a style derived from the mapbox-provided styles, in order to use my custom sprite, and served this style using https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl
4. In my layer configuration, I used a "symbol" type layer and selected the relevant icon by passing its name in the layout properties "icon-image" : "green-triangle-11"

I'll admit it's quite a lot of work to display a green triangle on a map !

---

**Edit (18-07-2017) :** I found out you can load any image and display it on the map, it doesn't have to be part of the style. I'm not sure if Mapbox added this recently or if I had missed it until now. Here goes :

```
map.loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cat_silhouette.svg/400px-Cat_silhouette.svg.png', (error, image) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    map.addImage('cat', image);
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "points",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [0, 0]
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "cat",
            "icon-size": 0.25
        }
    });
});
```

Taken from https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/